# Deleting data from two tables in one query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I got two tables which works the same way as a customer and the transactions that it made.
So one customer can have more than one transactions. And so when I delete the customer, I want to delete all the transactions that he has made.
Below is my 'customer' table where its has a `uuid` as the `PRIMARY KEY`

[image: customer]

Below is the 'transaction' table where the column `bird_id` is refered to the `uuid` column of the above table.

[image: transaction]

I have tried this.

```
WITH delete_bird_and_entry AS (
   select birdsdata.id from birdsdata
   LEFT JOIN 
   entries ON birdsdata.name = entries.bird_name and birdsdata.species = entries.species_name 
   where birdsdata.id = '6ca574a7-b515-4629-8aa6-4149fcef2bd8'
)

DELETE from birdsdata, entries where id IN (select id from delete_bird_and_entry);
```

But its not working as it gives me a syntax error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 8: DELETE from birdsdata, entries where id IN (select id from d...
```

Hope my question was clear. This is my first time dealing with postresql so not sure as to how to ask the question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Read about the constraint `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: You're error says there's a syntax error near a comma but I don't see a comma in your code at all, and I also second setting up a cascading delete constraint to make deletes like this easier

Comment: sorry i have edited my post. I think i accidentally delete some part

Answer (score 2):

Create a cascading foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE entries
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (bird_id) REFERENCES birdsdata(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Then delete the row in `birdsdata`, and the dependent rows will be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

A single DELETE statement can only delete from a single table. The cascading foreign key is one way to do it.

Another way is to chain the two delete statements using a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with deleted_birds as (
  delete from birdsdata
  where birdsdata.id = '6ca574a7-b515-4629-8aa6-4149fcef2bd8'
  returning id
)
delete from entries
where bird_id in (select id from deleted_birds);
```